# Browser does not automatically set request content type header for FormData with Fetch

Tags: javascript, multipartform-data, fetch-api, form-data

I am trying to upload a file using FormData, but the server does not receive the data.

Following a number posts and blogs that conclude setting content type header as multipart/form-data overrides the required format that includes "boundary", I removed the content type header assuming my browser is going to handle the request content type header. The web is flooded with this solution for formdata, but I could not find any case where the browser does not automatically set the content type when FormData is used. My server works fine, because I am able to successfully post requests from a REST client.

This is my API call :

```
const data = new FormData()
data.append('file', this.state.selectedFile)

const result = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/uploadResume", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Authorization": `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('user_token')}`
            },
            data: data
        })
```

These are the request headers set by the browser (Google Chrome) :

[image]

Is there a browser setting I am missing, or an other potential issue I am overlooking ?

**SOLVED**
I called the API with data set as 'data' instead of 'body' by mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Request object expects a `body` property

```
    fetch(url, {
        // data: data <-- wrong
        body: data // <-- correct
    })
```

---

### Off topic

judging by the small amount of data that you are sending (just one field/file) you could just simply post the data as raw bytes instead of having it be a FormData (makes it a tiny bit easier for the server to pipe the data to a file & doesn't have to process any FormData  algorithm) + you would know how large the file is beforehand when receiving it.

```
    fetch(url, {
        body: this.state.selectedFile
    })
```

all doe, you lose the filename but maybe you can just stick it in some x-filename header

Comment: Hey, thanks for pointing it out. After all the brainstorming, its a silly mistake! I agree with your suggestion about posting raw bytes. Thanks!